# Symmetry breaking and band gaps?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry-breaking, electronic-band-theory

Can the discontinuity in the E-K dispersion relation of a periodic lattice (at the boundary of a Brillouin zone) be understood as a consequence of breaking continuous translation symmetry into discrete translation symmetry? If yes, then what will be the logical progression of this argument?

Comment: Yes.   There are countless consequences.  Almost the entire modern field of solid state physics starts with that fact.